# Splash screen won't show, only blank space

Tags: java, android, xml, splash-screen

So created Splash screen png, putted it in drawable folder (created just one size to see how it looks on device) but when app launches it just doesn't show it, only white screen is shown.

Here's splash.java

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

        int secondsDelayed = 1;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, AppLayoutMain.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }, secondsDelayed * 1000);
    }
}
```

Here's XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView46"
        android:background="@drawable/splashscreen"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And Manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AppLayoutMain"/>
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Try increasing the time duration.

Answer (score 1):

move handler to onResume

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, AppLayoutMain.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }, secondsDelayed * 1000);
}
```

also change in xml

```
android:background="@drawable/splashscreen"
```

to

```
android:src="@drawable/splashscreen"
```

Answer (score 1):

try like so

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                nextActivity();
            }
        }, 3000);

    }

private void nextActivity() {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, AppLayoutMain.class);
                startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: this is the suggested trend by android devs (:, but i prefer old school.

Comment: I like branded launch, but it does not stay on the screen long enough

Answer (score 0):

you have forgot to put this line in xml

> xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView46"
    android:background="@drawable/splashscreen"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In the app? Yes it does